# python frisbeelite. Dont work wxPython

Tags: python, windows, pip, wxpython, attributeerror

I tried launching [Frisbeelite](https://github.com/nccgroup/FrisbeeLite) on Windows. 
I installed 2.7 python, pip, wxPython (wxPython-4.0.0a3-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl). Now, when i run frisbeelite.py, I get the following issue (on [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7g03.png) ):

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "FrisbeeLite_v1.2.py", line 722, in 
>       win = MainPanel(frame)
>       File "FrisbeeLite_v1.2.py", line 215, in **init**
>       self.statusbar = self.parent.CreateStatusBar(3, wx.ST_SIZEGRIP)
>       AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ST_SIZEGRIP'

How to fix it?

Comment: `ST_SIZEGRIP` is no longer referenced the same way in the latest version of wxPython. You will have to either down grade, modify Frisbeelite or alias that in the latest wxPython

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project seems to be rather old — the last commit was 4 years ago. wxPython 4.0 is too new. Try older versions from https://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/

Answer (score 0):

Edit the code to remove the offending argument (this argument is no longer required). I had the same issue updating a wxPython based Python 2 program to Python 3.

Change the line of code to read the following:

```
init self.statusbar = self.parent.CreateStatusBar(3)
```